# Getting Same Predictions for Every Class when Training YOLOv8m.pt with VisDrone 2019-Det Dataset

Tags: image-processing, dataset, object-detection, yolo, yolov8

I'm training the YOLOv8 model with the VisDrone 2019-Det dataset, but I'm getting same predictions for every class than normal-size expected. The training results are as follows:

[The result of epoch 1 , rest of the 10 epochs out of 100 are the same i stopped process after seeing it for 10 epoch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAXuO.png)

i used this repo for converting  visdrone-2019 dataset to correct format to yolov8 format [github repo](https://github.com/adityatandon/VisDrone2YOLO/tree/main)

here is my .yaml file:
[yaml file for directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/If8In.png)

yolo cli code:

`!yolo task=detect mode=train model=yolov8m.pt data= visdrone-dataset-config.yaml epochs=100 imgsz=640 batch=4 plots=True project=/content/drive/MyDrive/Teknofest/AFTERMATH/OUTPUT name=visdrone12`

I'm suspicious of the github repo i used to convert but can't be sure cause im new to image processing.